# php - remove html tags

Tags: php, jquery, contenteditable, strip-tags

I'm using the contenteditable feature on a personal project to update a sql database, however when I update the content it adds html tags into the database i.e.

```
<div id="lipsum" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; 
text-align:     justify; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: normal;">
 <p style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin-bottom: 14px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt tincidunt tellus, 
ac tincidunt magna imperdiet volutpat. Pellentesque pharetra lorem vitae velit gravida, 
eget gravida tellus volutpat. Praesent viverra nulla at arcu fringilla, quis semper ligula
```

What are my solutions in terms of stripping these tags out? Can i use jquery or php? Can anyone show me some working examples?

This is the code I am using to update my database

save.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$content = $_POST['content'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];//get posted data
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);  
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);//escape string   

$sql = "UPDATE datadump SET firstname = '$firstname', content = '$content' WHERE id = '1'";
if (mysql_query($sql))
{
    echo 1;
}
?>
```

js/js.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#content').html(); 
        var firstname = $('#firstname').html();     
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {content: content, firstname: firstname},             
            success:function (data) {

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data saved successfully")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data saved successfully")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
            }
        });   

    });

    $("#maincontent").click(function (e) {
        $("#save").show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#save").hide();  
    });

});
```

Comment: you are looking for [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: @rob do i want strip_tags rather than mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: You probably want both. You should really stop using mysql_* functions though and start using pdo or mysqli.

Comment: ok i see, yeah i know i just wanted to whip something up quickly using simple php to see if this would actually work and it does and its a pretty cool feature to play around with @Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Change this;

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
```

To this;

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags( $content ) );
```