# Strip HTML tags before putting them in a database

Tags: php, html

I have a posting system, but I don't want people to be able to use HTML tags when posting, here's the code for the database query.

```
 if (!empty($post1) && !empty($title)) {
  strip_tags($post1);
    // Only set the picture column if there is a new picture
$query = "INSERT INTO kaoscraft_posts (`username`, `rank`, `gender`, `picture`, `post_date`, `title`, `post`, `category`) VALUES ('$username', '$rank', '$gender', '$picture', NOW(), '$title', '$post1', '$category')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Here's the form

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MM_MAXFILESIZE; ?>" />
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Post Here:</legend>
        <label type="hidden" for="title">Title:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="title"><br /><br />
      <select id="category" name="category">
        <option value="G" <?php if (!empty($category) && $category == 'G') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>General</option>
        <option value="Srv" <?php if (!empty($category) && $category == 'G') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Server</option>
        <option value="C" <?php if (!empty($category) && $category == 'G') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Clan</option>
        <option value="SA" <?php if (!empty($category) && $category == 'G') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Staff App</option>
        <option value="V" <?php if (!empty($category) && $category == 'G') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Videos</option>
      </select><br /><br />
      <label type="hidden" for="post1">Post Content:</label><br />
      <textarea rows="4"  name="post1" id="post1" cols="50"></textarea><br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Post" name="submit" />     
  </form>
```

Comment: Your PHP is vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - remove html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283023/php-remove-html-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a built in function for this purpose: strip_tags. The example from their site:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

So you would just add strip_tags($post1); before adding (or during) it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign the `$post1` after you call `strip_tags` on it.

```
$post1 = strip_tags($post1);
```

Also, unless you have some solid SQL escaping code somewhere else, I ***strongly*** recommend looking into securing your code from SQL injection. If you are directly putting user input into your SQL query, they could input malicious SQL statements.